# iostat disk utilization is full when there is no IO happening

Tags: rhel, iostat

I'm doing iostat on RHEL-6.6 machine and the results shown by 2 columns are difficult to understand.

```
iostat -xm 1
```

result:

```
avgqu-sz = a large number (42353468)
%util = 100%
```

There is absolutely no IO happening to any of the disks. The disk is not mounted on to any of the mount points. Can anyone please explain the reason for this?

Comment: It would be easier for others to see the complete output of the `iostat` command. But it seems there is IO happening in your system. Maybe you can invoke `iotop` to find the process that generates the IO.

Comment: I even checked with `iotop` and there is no process that is doing the IO. I'm using SSD here. Is it the problem with the driver?